# Using DOT as thousand separator in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to format a decimal number 123456.789 as 123.456,78 in python 2.7 without using locale?

Thousand separator should be DOT instead of COMMA and decimal separator should be COMMA instead of DOT.

Is there any quick way to convert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really, really want to avoid `locale` then you could work with the value returned from `format(val, ',')` and then swap the `,` and `.`:

```
>>> a = 1234567.89
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> trans = maketrans('.,', ',.')
>>> format(a, ',.2f').translate(trans)
'1.234.567,89'
```

Comment: can bot seperators be `.`?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to change your [`locale`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_DEU')
'German_Germany.1252'
>>> "{0:n}".format(12345.67)
'12.345,7'
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'English_United Kingdom.1252'
>>> "{0:n}".format(12345.67)
'12,345.7'
>>>
```